# each vs for loops and why my 'each' example is much faster

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

i've found a couple of questions here about `$.each` and `for` loops and everyone  say that `for` is much faster. But i have this example https://jsfiddle.net/ffu7L5oj/2/ where `each` 2 times faster. Can someone explaine me why? I dont get it at all :c

Comment: I don't see the each look being faster than the for loop in your fiddle

Comment: There is no [mcve] in the question itself

Comment: This is to do with the browser caching the DOM. If you reverse the order of the tests then `for` is faster: https://jsfiddle.net/ffu7L5oj/6/

Comment: As other people have mentioned, your benchmark is flawed. Averaging out a large number of runs shows the jQuery version to be ~11% slower: https://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/1

Comment: Wow, forgot about caching and stuff, thank a lot!

Answer (score -1):

JQuery is nothing more that an API that wraps native JavaScript. It is virtually impossible for a JQuery operation to be faster than its pure JavaScript counterpart since the JQuery call is just going to call the lower-level JavaScript.